# When JOINing 3 tables in Postgres, can the results be sorted by values in the 2 joined tables?

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-order-by

I have a database with three tables. Ultimately I want to JOIN the three tables and sort them by a column shared by two of the tables.

A main item table with foreign keys (product_id) to the two sub-tables:

**items**

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    product_id varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    type CHAR NOT NULL
);
```

and then a table corresponding to each typeA and typeB. They have differing columns, but for the sake of this exercise I'm only including the columns they have in common:

```
CREATE TABLE products_a (
    id varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    price INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE products_b (
    id varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    price INT NOT NULL
);
```

Some example rows:

```
INSERT INTO items VALUES 
( 1, 'abc', 'a' ),
( 2, 'def', 'b' ),
( 3, 'ghi', 'a' ),
( 4, 'jkl', 'b' );

INSERT INTO products_a VALUES 
( 'abc', 'product 1', 10 ),
( 'ghi', 'product 2', 50 );

INSERT INTO products_b VALUES 
( 'def', 'product 3', 20 ),
( 'jkl', 'product 4', 100 );
```

I have a JOIN working, but my sorting is not interpolating the rows as I would expect.

Query:

```
SELECT
    items.id AS item_id,
    products_a.name AS product_a_name,
    products_a.price AS product_a_price,
    products_b.name AS product_b_name,
    products_b.price AS product_b_price
FROM items
FULL JOIN products_a ON items.product_id = products_a.id
FULL JOIN products_b ON items.product_id = products_b.id
ORDER BY 3, 5 ASC;
```

Actual result:

| item_id | product_a_name | product_a_price | product_b_name | product_b_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product 1 | 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | product 2 | 50 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | product 3 | 20 |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | product 4 | 100 |

Desired result:

| item_id | product_a_name | product_a_price | product_b_name | product_b_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product 1 | 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | product 3 | 20 |
| 3 | product 2 | 50 | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | product 4 | 100 |

I realize this is a weird table setup, but simplified this way looks more contrived than it is. Ultimately the sorting matches the real use case, though, and changing the DB schema is not an option. I feel like I am missing something simple here, just sorting by either one column or another. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` in the `ORDER BY` clause to always sort by the first non `NULL` price:

```sql
SELECT
    items.id AS item_id,
    products_a.name AS product_a_name,
    products_a.price AS product_a_price,
    products_b.name AS product_b_name,
    products_b.price AS product_b_price
FROM items
FULL JOIN products_a ON items.product_id = products_a.id
FULL JOIN products_b ON items.product_id = products_b.id
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(3, 5);
```